# Getting unexptected data with SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, join

This may seem like a basic question, but I'm having a SQL issue. I have two tables, `YesterdayData`, and `_ListSubscribers`.  They each have a `Primary Key` in common to join on SubscriberKey. However, I only want to return rows from `YesterdayData` that have data that doesn't match `_ListSubscribers` (and not rows from `_ListSubscribers` that don't exist in `YesterdayData`).

This is what I have so far, but it it returning many more rows than expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
y.ListName,
y.Status,
y.ListID,
y.SubscriberKey,
y.AddMethod
FROM _Listsubscribers l
LEFT JOIN YesterdayData y
ON y.subscriberkey = l.subscriberkey
WHERE l.Status != y.Status
```

thanks so much!
Greg

Update - thank you all for your help.  I believe this solved the issue:

```
SELECT
l.ListName,
l.Status,
l.ListID,
l.SubscriberKey,
l.AddMethod
FROM _Listsubscribers l
LEFT JOIN YesterdayData y
ON y.subscriberkey = l.subscriberkey
WHERE l.Status != y.Status
AND y.ListID = l.ListID
```

Adding the ListID condition (another primary key) seems to have fixed it.

thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for this sample.

Comment: Do you want to return _ListSubscriber records which are in YesterdayData but have the same status? If not, than you used the wrong join, use regular JOIN (inner) instead of LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.  I want to return all records in YesterdayData that have different values from what is in _ListSubscribers.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS The "many more rows" is because you want input row pairs "that have data that doesn't match" *but with other data matching*--but you forgot to add that to the ON. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: So your code at the moment is looking for rows for the same `SubscriberKey` where the `Status` is different. If that's what you want then assuming that `SubscriberKey` is, as you say, the common primary key, the query in your post should be good. However if the same person subscribes to multiple lists do the rows in your table still have the same `SubscriberKey`? If so, then that field isn't the primary key of these tables after all, and you'll need to expand the `ON` to include the other PK fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
Select 
y.ListName,
y.Status,
y.ListID,
y.SubscriberKey,
y.AddMethod 
From _Listsubscribers l 
Right Join YesterdayData y 
ON y.subscriberkey = l.subscriberkey 
WHERE l.Status != y.Status
```

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Please format your code reasonably. Please explain how your post solves the problem.

Comment: OK, Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try an inner join

```
SELECT DISTINCT
y.ListName,
y.Status,
y.ListID,
y.SubscriberKey,
y.AddMethod
FROM _Listsubscribers l
INNER JOIN YesterdayData y
ON y.subscriberkey = l.subscriberkey AND l.Status != y.Status
```

Answer (score 0):

You full join to get your desired set of results as below-

```
SELECT DISTINCT
y.ListName,
y.Status,
y.ListID,
y.SubscriberKey,
y.AddMethod
FROM _Listsubscribers l
FULL JOIN YesterdayData y
ON y.subscriberkey = l.subscriberkey
WHERE y.subscriberkey IS NULL OR  l.subscriberkey IS NULL
```

Comment: The question is not clear but a full join isn't consistent with what is written. Also not all SQLs have full join, so you don't know if this is appropriate, so please first comment for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `_Listsubscribers` where it is true that any (and I mean **any**) `YesterdayData` item exists with a different `Status`. You would need to find `YesterdayData` records which have no match in the `_Listsubscribers` `table`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
y.ListName,
y.Status,
y.ListID,
y.SubscriberKey,
y.AddMethod
FROM _Listsubscribers l
LEFT JOIN YesterdayData y
ON y.subscriberkey = l.subscriberkey
WHERE l.Status != y.Status
```

Try this way:

```
select y.ListName, y.Status, y.ListID, y.SubscriberKey, y.AddMethod
from YesterdayData y
where not exists (select 1 from _Listsubscribers l where l.Status = y.Status)
```

Explanation: If you have A and B sets where there is at least a single B record which does not match a given record of A, then the given record of A will be in the result, regardless of whether it has a match on B or not.

Example: there are horse riders and horses. We are interested to know a horse rider who has no horse. You have done something similar to searching for a rider if there is at least a horse, which is not his. If there is at least such a horse for each rider, then all riders will be considered to have no horse, regardless of whether they have a horse or not.